# How do I prevent an action from modifying a cookie?

Tags: java, http, cookies, playframework, playframework-1.x

I want to make sure my method doesn't modify certain cookies such as PLAY_FLASH and PLAY_SESSION (Why? Because of [bug 785](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987-play-framework/tickets/785-lost-session-information-working-with-suspended-requests)).

I tried this:

```
// This method should never modify any PLAY cookie.
public static void doNothingPost() throws InterruptedException {
    logger.info("Done nothing");

    response.cookies.remove("PLAY_FLASH");
    response.cookies.remove("PLAY_ERRORS");
    response.cookies.remove("PLAY_SESSION");

    ok();
}
```

Well, it turns out that `respone.cookies.remove()` will actively delete a cookie (SetCookie with a past expiry date). How do I just tell play not to send any SetCookie header for a specific cookie? (Or all of them?)

Comment: Also on the forums: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/kP5wb79OcIw

Answer (score 0):

- t0 -> call setSession
- t5 -> call doNothing
- t10 -> setSession returns
- t15 -> doNothing returns

  ```
  public static void setSession(String uuid){
      Cache.add(uuid, "guven");
      response.setCookie("username", "guven");
      await(1000);
      ok();
  }

  public static void doNothing(String sameUUIDWithSetSessionParameter){
      String username = Cache.get(sameUUIDWithSetSessionParameter, String.class);
      Cache.delete(sameUUIDWithSetSessionParameter);
      Logger.info("dn: " + username);
      await(1000);
      ok();
  }
  ```

if these consecutive ajax calls does not have different session ids, then forget the uuid parameter, just use `session.getId()` to get value from `Cache`